# How to represent the sentence "If everyone votes then the motion passes" with FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Should it be `∀x Votes(x) ⟹ Passes(Motion)`?

Probably not, because if none but 'John' votes, then using extended interpretation, `Votes(John) ⟹ Passes(Motion)` implies that `Passes(Motion)` is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between
$$\bigl[\forall x\;V(x)\bigr]\Rightarrow P(M) $$
and
$$ \forall x\bigl[V(x)\Rightarrow P(M)\bigr] $$

The first one is what captures the sense of the English sentence; the second one is what you need for your John counterexample to work.

Unfortunately there's no really strong consensus about how far to the right a quantifier applies when there are no brackets, so there's a real potential for confusion here. One just has to be very careful about checking which convention each particular author uses.

Comment: Got it, thanks.